# install Iphone SDK 4.0 on top of 4.2

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk, ipad

There is a nasty bug in IOS 4.2 having to do with the tint color of the navigation bar in a split view controller.

I have the 4.2 sdk on my mac, is there a way to install 4.0 on top of it and have them both work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant SDKs live in:

- /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs, and
- /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

In the past I've been able to keep an SDK from a previous version by simply copying the relevant folder forwards. Xcode simply spotted the old SDK and continued offering it as a Base SDK. So you'd need to install the old SDK somewhere, keep hold of the relevant iPhoneOS4.0.sdk and iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk folders, install the new SDK and then copy the backed up folders in. If you use Time Machine, you may even be able to grab them directly from there.

However, I believe this to be an unsupported way of proceeding, so it's not necessarily guaranteed to work. And all the usual warnings about doing anything Apple don't support apply.

Comment: Luckily I have an older Mac with 4.0 on it. We'll see if it works!